# create user with respone if success and two inputs of the password

Tags: powershell

i want to create a local admin account. how can i realize a output if the operation was successfull or not? and how can i realize that i need to input the same password twice for safety reasons for example i made a mistake? if the passwords are incorrect i need to type them again

```
$admin = read-host "Name"
$Password = Read-Host "Passwort" -AsSecureString
        New-LocalUser -Name "$admin" -password $password -Description "$admin" -FullName      "$admin" 
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Name "administrators" -Member "$admin"
        Set-LocalUser -Name "$admin" -PasswordNeverExpires 1 -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayChangePassword 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a endless loop.

Something like below:

```
$userName          = Read-Host "Name"
$securePassword    = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$plainTextPassword = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("someone", $securePassword).Password
while ($true) {
    $securePassword2 = Read-Host "Retype the password. Leave empty to cancel." -AsSecureString
    # convert the SecureString to plain text
    $plainTextPassword2 = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("someone", $securePassword2).Password
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($plainTextPassword2)) { return }  # cancel: exit the script
    if ($plainTextPassword -ceq $plainTextPassword2) { break }         # both passwords are equal, break the loop
}

try {
    $newUser = New-LocalUser -Name $userName -Password $securePassword -Description $userName -FullName $userName -ErrorAction Stop
    $newUser | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true -UserMayChangePassword $false -AccountNeverExpires -ErrorAction Stop
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $userName -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    throw $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. maybe you can help me with my other problem. would be nice if i get a message if the account was created successfully or not. and when it is not created correctly the reason why not

Comment: @chkdsk Please see my edited answer. Now, if an error occurs on any of the `*-LocalUser` cmdlets, you will see the error message.

Comment: your script runs fine but i still have a little note. how can i leave the powershell window open after the error message. at the moment it closes immediately

Comment: @chkdsk Then replace `throw $_.Exception.Message` with `Write-Warning $($_.Exception.Message)`

Comment: i think a `read-host` helped me out. Nevertheless thank you for your help. the rest of your code works absolutely fine